# How can I style the label in the Recharts Brush component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, recharts

As can be seen in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-curran-si0i3?file=/src/App.js) when you put your mouse over the Brush, a label appears with the data, this date changes appropriately as you move the slider on the brush. But in its default position, the label is off screen at both the left and right.

From reading the [doc's](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Brush) there doesn't appear to be field available for styling the tooltip label like there is with other Recharts components nor does there look to be any options available for applying padding to Brush to allow it to be smaller than the area available, giving space for the label to show.

Does anyone have any tips? Below the code from the CodeSandbox linked can be seen.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import {
  ResponsiveContainer,
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Brush
} from "recharts";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    { interval: "2021-01-01", resultCount: 2 },
    { interval: "2021-01-03", resultCount: 7 },
    { interval: "2021-01-05", resultCount: 1 },
    { interval: "2021-01-08", resultCount: 10 },
    { interval: "2021-01-10", resultCount: 2 },
    { interval: "2021-01-11", resultCount: 9 },
    { interval: "2021-01-15", resultCount: 5 },
    { interval: "2021-01-18", resultCount: 8 },
    { interval: "2021-01-21", resultCount: 0 },
    { interval: "2021-01-22", resultCount: 7 }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ResponsiveContainer width={500} height={300}>
        <LineChart data={data}>
          <YAxis
            dataKey="resultCount"
            label={{
              value: "No. of Posts",
              angle: -90,
              position: "insideLeft"
            }}
          />
          <XAxis
            dataKey="interval"
            label={{ value: "Time (day)", position: "bottom" }}
          />
          <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
          <Line
            strokeWidth={2}
            dataKey="resultCount"
            stroke="#127ABF"
            dot={{ stroke: "#127ABF", strokeWidth: 3, fill: "#127ABF" }}
            isAnimationActive={false}
          />
          <Brush dataKey="interval" />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; Use the `stroke` prop (not documented, but explained below)

The Brush component (https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/cartesian/Brush.tsx) takes in SVGProps from react, so you can style the component like so:

```
<Brush
  stroke="green"
/>
```

It also seems, even though that it isn't documented (https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Brush) that you can pass a custom `traveller` which can be a custom svg element (I haven't tried this yet, but can be seen in source file).

Hope this helps! (I found this while searching for an answer, but reading source code *eventually* lead me to the `stroke` prop.

Comment: FWIW their brush component is horrible and I ended up coding my own and I'm much happier (material ui slider: https://material-ui.com/components/slider/)